# Zookeeper resiliency

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We have cluster of 17 brokers and 5 zookeepers. I wanted to test resiliency of zookeepers. So I took down 3 zookeepers as my understanding is that for a cluster with 5 zookeepers the maximum outage it can withstand is failure of 2 ( using 2n+1 rule) zookeepers. But to my surprise I was able to produce & consume  data. And even with all the zookeepers ( i.e. all 5) down I was able to produce data. Can some explain the reason behind the two behaviors ?

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper is only required for notifications when there are changes happening to the cluster.  Say, brokers joining the cluster or going down.  If all brokers are running, and there's consumers/producers connected to it and sending/receiving data, there's no need for zookeeper communication, and everything will just keep working.  *New* producer/consumer connections might not work, but I'm not 100% confident of that.

When brokers join/leave the cluster, consumers need to be notified, so they can point to the correct leaders for the partitions/topics they're consuming from.  Also, other brokers need to be notified to start syncing data to the new broker, or to take on leadership for topic/partitions that are now leaderless.  All those notifications are sent through zookeeper.

There's many more details at these links:

https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-kafka/the-role-of-apache-zookeeper-in-apache-kafka/read

https://data-flair.training/blogs/zookeeper-in-kafka/

Comment: Hi @mjuarez , thanks for the detailed response. Producer can produce with less number of zookeepers. However the topic describe command which requires zookeeper stops working when we have less than 2n+1 zookeepers available. But sometimes that also doesn't work when I bring back enough zookeepers from stopped to running state to satisfy 2n+1. Meaning on a 5 node zookeeper quorum , even with 3 zookeepers topic describe didn't work. When the 4th node was brought up it started to work and then stopping 4th again didn't impact it . Not sure how to explain this bahavior. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Anirban Sounds like you are not running newest Kafka CLI which does not require Zookeeper. Also producers/consumers have not needed Zookeeper since 0.8 release years ago, and even then, number of ZK was not important as long as it isn't 0

Answer (score -1):

Kafka can operate just fine without Zookeeper as long as there is no need to change the In Sync Replicas. Kafka would start throwing errors once there's any update in the ISR for any partition when brokers bounce/joins.

Comment: Not just ISR, but also creating, deleting, or altering any topic or adding/removing a broker